# Using JS color value stored in an array, to style a P5.js Dom element

Tags: javascript, css, processing, p5.js

I am creating DOM buttons in [P5.js](https://p5js.org/), that I want to apply styling to. In this case I want to change the background color. Normally this would be applied by doing this.

```js
button.style("background-color", "black");
```

In my case I want to reference a color already stored in a JS array, as the colors are being uniformly used, like this.

```js
swatch.style("background-color", colArray[0]);
```

Obviously this does not work, as the style is being applied from CSS. Any suggestions would be aces.

I could store the colors in CSS and reference a style, but I am trying to avoid double handling.

No error messages in the console for JS. Just a plain CSS issue.

Comment: Can you give example how you store colors in array. Does them hex color codes or just strings like `black`,`white` etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the color value directly because it's an object that CSS doesn't understand, but you can format it into a string that CSS does understand. In p5.js you can use the `red()`, `green()`, and `blue()` functions to get the RGB values from the color.

Then once you have those values, I can think of two approaches:

**Approach one:** In CSS, use the [`rgb()`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgb.asp) function. It would look something like this:

```
var rgbString = 'rgb(' + red(myColor) + ', ' + green(myColor) + ', ' + blue(myColor) + ')';
myElement.style('background-color', rgbString);
```

**Approach two:** In p5.js, use the `hex()` function to convert the RGB values into hex.

```
var rHex = hex(red(myColor));
var gHex = hex(green(myColor));
var bHex = hex(blue(myColor));
var hexColor = '#' + rHex + gHex + bHex;
myElement.style('background-color', hexColor);
```

I haven't tested this so some of the syntax might be slightly off, but hopefully that gives you the general idea.